# Delphi - View with parameter

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I have the following View:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW "ButtonGroup_ButtonNames_view"("ButtonName")
AS
select "ButtonName"
from   "ButtonGroupName_ButtonName"
where  "ButtonGroupName_ButtonName"."ButtonGroupName" = ':lButtonGroupName'
```

The `':lButtonGroupName'` is suppoused to work as a parameter, so at runtime I can set a value to it.

When I run the application, I get the `parameter name not found` error. I guess this is not the correct way to declare a `parameter` inside a `view`. Is it possible anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes of the parameter like `where  "ButtonGroupName_ButtonName"."ButtonGroupName" = :lButtonGroupName`

Comment: If you have an existing view, please post the DDL for it, because your Sql looks improbable to me.  Also, what Sql back-end are you writing for?

Comment: @RRUZ. I have try that and got an SQL error `token unknown`

Comment: @MartynA. The above is the existing SQL. It was registered on the Database. By the way, it is a `FireBird 2.5` database. Your are saying that is not possible to declare a parameter in a view, as in a query?

Comment: You can't create a view with a parameter, AFAIK. You can provide the parameter in the `SELECT ... FROM <view>` when you use it. Why are you repeatedly calling `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` anyway? The VIEW should be created once  on the server, and only modified if the actual **code** in that view changes.

Comment: In most databases it is not possible to create a view with a parameter, I always thought this was so for all databases.

Comment: @Ken White. I'm not repeatedly calling CREATE OR ALTER VIEW, IBExpert is doing so, every time I modify the view.

Comment: @Ken White. I already had hat feeling that is not possible to insert a parameter into a view. Thanks for your confirmation. Instead, it is possible to provide that parameter via stored preocedure?

Comment: "Instead, it is possible to provide that parameter via stored preocedure?" Yes.

Comment: @Val Marinov. Thanks for your answer. Can you provide a simple example on how to do so?

Comment: *IBExpert is doing so* - Yes, when you're **designing** the view. You should not need to do so from your code, which is the only place you would need a parameter.

Comment: ОК.  `create or alter procedure MY_PROCEDURE (
    PARAM_1 integer)
returns (
    OUT_RESULT integer)
as
begin
  select t.my_field from my_table t where t.id = :param_1
  suspend;
end`

Comment: @Val Marinov. Thanks. I take your answer as correct. One more little help (if you can be so kind). How I use that proc at runtime in Delphi.

Comment: @Val Marinov. I tried:

Comment: You **don't** create views or stored procedures at runtime. This is getting silly. Find yourself a good tutorial or book, and learn what VIEWs and STORED PROCEDUREs are and how to use them. You don't CREATE OR ALTER stored procedures or views at runtime. You set them up on the server, and then SELECT from the VIEW or EXECUTE the stored procedure from your code at runtime. If you don't know what they are and how they work, you need to learn before using them.

Comment: @Val Marinov. Sorry

Comment: [This should help](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+SQL+view&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) you understand what a VIEW is and how you should use one.

Comment: @Ken White. With all due respect, your'e getting all wrong. I don't know how you jumped to this conclusion. Is not my intent to create any stored procedure at run time. It's clear to me that it is created using a DBMS (I1m using IBExpert). Thanks for your kindly suggestion. I will take it into account.

Comment: You keep asking how you can call CREATE OR ALTER at run time. What do you expect me to think? I've told you that you SELECT from a VIEW, and you can pass a parameter to that SELECT at runtime. You chose not to listen, move on to incorrectly trying to use a stored procedure the same way, which is also just as wrong, and you're not listening when told not  to do that either. The only conclusion to be drawn from your repeated attempts to do the wrong thing using the wrong methods is that you don't understand what you're doing. If you understood what a VIEW is, you'd understand how to use it.

Comment: @Ken White. I kIindly insist that that is not my intent. I don't want to go further into this discussion and I appologize if, by any means, I was unrespectful to you. In the future, if you don't feel comfortable with my questions, please ignore them. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131278/discussion-between-ppro-and-ken-white).

Comment: I've answered your question. You **CANNOT PASS A PARAMETER TO A VIEW**. You **SELECT** from the VIEW, and pass the parameter **TO THAT SELECT**. I'm not sure what part of that you're having difficulty understanding. I'm unable to continue this in chat, because I'm headed out for a meeting. I can't say it any more plainly anyway; it's clear you're not listening.

Answer (score 0):

That's now how views work. You can provide parameters on the `select` query you use to fetch results from a view, but the view itself cannot have any parameters. There's no facility for passing parameters to a view that aren't already part of the query.

There wouldn't really be any optimization from such a "parameterized view" anyway. The database engine couldn't prefetch results because it won't know the parameter value until you do the query. Knowing that a certain column is parameterized, the database engine *could* make an index on that column, but you can just as easily index the column in the underlying table. The query against the view will use the same indices as a query against the table would.