# Delphi Stored Procedure can't recognize param

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and IBExpert.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE "ButtonGroupName_proc" ("ButtonGroupName_in" "SystemObjectName")
returns ("ButtonGroupName_out" "SystemObjectName")
as
begin
  for
    select "ButtonName"
    from   "ButtonGroupName_ButtonName"
    where  "ButtonGroupName_ButtonName"."ButtonGroupName" = :"ButtonGroupName_in"
    into   :"ButtonGroupName_out"
  do
  suspend;
end
^
SET TERM ; ^
```

At runtime I coded:

```
...
var
  lStoredProc : tFDStoredProc;
...
lStoredProc := tFDStoredProc.Create (Application);
  with lStoredProc do begin
        Connection     := dmSysData.SysData_Connection;
        StoredProcName := DoubleQuotedStr ('ButtonGroupName_proc');
        ParamByName ('ButtonGroupName_in').Value := 'ButtonGroup_System_Tasks';
        Open;
        ...
    end;
```

When running, I get the "parameter 'ButtonGroupName_in' not found" error, though it is declared as input paramter in the Stored Procedure, as can be verified from the script above.

The code above, was adapted from a very similar example from the Web, but it doesn't work with my code.

Comment: I can point out what's wrong. You're [still insisting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41285510/62576) on ignoring what people are telling you about how to do it right, and still insisting on trying to force your ill-conceived ideas of how VIEWs and STORED PROCEDUREs work. Once again (for about the fifth time from me): You don't pass parameters like this to a VIEW or STORED PROCEDURE. What you're trying  to do is incorrect, and you're insisting on trying to do it anyway. The proper way is to create the view, and then pass your parameter into the SELECT that you do against that view.

Comment: Well, that's not what Embarcadero says about Stored Procedures:

Comment: with SQLStoredProc1 do    begin
      ParamByName('IN_OUTVAR').AsInteger := 103;
      ExecProc;
      IntegerVar := ParamByName('IN_OUTVAR').AsInteger;
    end;

Comment: with SQLStoredProc1 do
    begin
      ParamByName('IN_OUTVAR').AsInteger := 103;
      ExecProc;
      IntegerVar := ParamByName('IN_OUTVAR').AsInteger;
    end;

Comment: Extracted from 

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Working_with_Stored_Procedure_Parameters

Comment: @MartynA. I found the "with" construct very handy. It saves a lot of repetitions of the same token and I think is much clear to read the code. But still, might be a question of preference.

Comment: @MartynA. Would you figure, by chance, what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I agree with everything @KenWhite has said on this q and your one earlier.  As far as I can see, the "problem" is that you're not listening to him.

Comment: You're still not listening. **You're using stored procedures inappropriately.** The documentation says stored procedures accepts params, and that's correct. What the documentation **does not say** is that insistently trying to use stored procedures for the wrong purpose will work. You ***really*** need to find a good SQL book or tutorial to learn the basics. (And you should listen to @MartynA about the use of `with`. Using it may seem convenient, but it also causes much more hard to track down bugs in your code. It's a laziness tool that EMBT has been discussing removing for a couple years.)

Comment: I'm surprised that you're (wrongly) willing to listen to what you think EMBT is saying, anyway. I'm surprised you're asking questions here. You **clearly** don't want to listen to those trying to help you (Rob Kennedy and me in your other question, MartynA and me in this question), so why bother to ask? (And stored procedure names are not passed as *DoubleQuotedString*s either.)

Comment: EMBT discussing to remove the "with" construct is new for me, but for any reason it wasn't removed. I think that any peace of code can be "bad coded". Is a matter of be disciplined and code the most clearly possible. This is one of my main concerns when I code. The fact of using or not the "with" construct, does not mean that the code will be legible and understandable. Conversely, I think that when it is judiciously used, it can enhance the readability and the understanding of the code. But still, is my opinion, wich I think I have the right to express, without being criticized.

Comment: It's very likely to be removed in an upcoming version, according to Marco Cantu (the Product Manager). But state your opinion all you want - you don't work with me (thankfully), so you can feel free to write all the bad code you like. It's also irrelevant to this or your last question here, both of which are related to your general lack of understanding of SQL and both of which are going to remain unanswered until you start listening to people here. If you don't want to listen to what people are telling you, just delete your questions and stop wasting our time.

Comment: You say, in your own words: "You're using stored procedures inappropriately", but you didn't provide a single example of the appropriate use. Why the Embarcadero Wiki provides such example if it is not apppropriate to use? In wich context it is appropriate? Can you clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: I've explained a dozen times. You need a **SELECT**. If it's a complicated relationship between several tables, you can create a VIEW and then SELECT from that VIEW. In both cases, you pass the parameter to the SELECT. There is zero need for a stored procedure here, and there was zero need for a VIEW in either of the simple pieces of SQL you've posted in your two questions. I don't know how I can say it any clearer, or how many times I have to repeat it before you actually read the words. You can find examples of the appropriate use of stored procs in the SQL tutorial or book I keep suggesting

Comment: It's very clear you have little or no knowledge of SQL, and you're stuck on a solution you've fixated on for some reason, and it's the wrong solution. I've told you that several times, @MartynA has told you that, RobKennedy told you that in a response to your other post, and you've ignored all of us and insisted that you need to use a view or stored proc. **If you're not going to listen to what we tell you, why are you asking here in the first place?**

Comment: I already run a test with a Stored Procedure, passing a parameter as showed in the Wiki and it worked:

Comment: The code:
    lStoredProc := tFDStoredProc.Create (Application);
      with lStoredProc do begin
            Connection     := dmSysData.SysData_Connection;
            StoredProcName :=   DoubleQuotedStr ('ButtonGroupName_proc');
            Params.Clear;
            Params [0] := tFDParam.Create (Params, ptInput);
            Params [0].Name := 'ButtonGroupName';
            ParamByName ('ButtonGroupName').Value := 'ButtonGroup_System_Tasks';
            Open;
            ...

Answer (score 0):

Although Delphi can infer parameters from a SELECT statement automatically by parsing the contents of the `SQL` property, it cannot do the same for the parameters of a stored procedure, so you need to define them explicitly with the `Params` array:

```
lStoredProc := tFDStoredProc.Create (Application);
  with lStoredProc do begin
        Connection     := dmSysData.SysData_Connection;
        StoredProcName :=   DoubleQuotedStr ('ButtonGroupName_proc');
        Params.Clear;
        Params [0] := tFDParam.Create (Params, ptInput);
        Params [0].Name := 'ButtonGroupName';
        ParamByName ('ButtonGroupName').Value := 'ButtonGroup_System_Tasks';
        Open;
           while   not Eof do begin
                 lButtonName := Fields [0].Value;
                  Next;
           end;
```

It retrieves what I need: that is, the names of the buttons that belong to a specific Group of buttons.

Comment: So does a simple `SELECT`, without the overhead of creating a stored procedure for such a simple query. Your code may technically work (which is why I'm not downvoting it), but it's still the wrong solution to the actual problem you're trying to solve. *Look, Pa! I found out how to drive a screw using this sledgehammer!* is seldom the right approach. Learn to work on finding a solution to your actual problem (X) instead of trying to solve problem Y (the problem you caused by not solving X in the first place).

Comment: Your'e right, a simple Select will do, but not for my porpouses, wich is to automatize the acces to the DB. First, I used a tFDquery, implying on assembly the Select and then passing the value. It worked fine, but I found it a bit complicated. The next step, was to use a View, but views don't take parameters. Using a Stored Proc, the Select is already assembled, need only to pass the value. The good things about Views and Procs is that they are easy to create using a DBMS, plus they are stored in the DB itself, wich is good. My next try will be your suggestion (a Select to a View). Thanks.

Comment: Using the SQL property of the query, the SELECT is already assembled, and it becomes two lines of code to execute it (one to set the parameter, and one to open the query). Creating the stored procedure does not *automatize* (which isn't a word, BTW - the proper one is *automate*) anything. You're now using 9 lines of code in your app (plus the code in the DB for the stored proc) to do something you could do in two (plus a line or two of SQL in the property editor). Not an improvement. And a view is totally useless as well, because views are to encapsulate *complex SELECT statements*.

Comment: (continued)  I also never suggested you use a SELECT from a VIEW. I said that's the proper way to use parameters with a VIEW. The view is also totally wrong to use here. You're still refusing to learn, staying fixated on the sledgehammer approach. I give up. There comes a time when trying to pound understanding into a stone becomes too much effort; you've obviously got your mind made up to take the absolutely wrong approach here, and as I've said before we don't work together, so you're free to write all the bad code you'd like.

Comment: In my HPOV, your'e the one that refuses to see my point of view. This is because you don't have a clue about my project and I don't intent to tell you, because you will not understand any way. My question was very simple: how I pass parameters to a SP. Instead of answer, you (really) wasted your time trying to convince me that it is not possible. You were wrong! Thank you for correcting me about the "automate" word. I'm pretty sure that in 100 years you will be far to write in portuguese as I write in English.

Comment: No, I **did not** say it was not possible. I've said all along that you're choosing the wrong solution to the problem, which you've refused to hear even though you've been told that by three far more experienced people than yourself. If you're more comfortable writing in Portugese, there's a [Stack Overflow for you here](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/). I was trying to help you correct a mistake, not insulting, but like everything else I've said you don't appreciate that either. As I said, I'm finished here. I'll go help people who actually want to learn instead. Good luck.

Comment: The same for you.

Comment: @KenWhite, *"You're now using 9 lines of code in your app (plus the code in the DB for the stored proc) to do something you could do in two (plus a line or two of SQL in the property editor)"*. Nothing wrong with using a SP even it's short. keeping logic in the DB layer has it's advantages. if the logic changes in the future you change the SP in the DB layer, and do not need to re-distribute your application where you hardcoded the SQL statements.

Comment: (continued) Besides, I don't think that the aim of this site is to teach other people how to code, but to solve its coding problems. If you know the answer, you put it in a comment, if not, you simply abstain to comment. I don't think that is nice behavoir to say that "you know nothing about ..." or "you must learn more about..". Is my choice, and only mine, the way I code (and my responsability too). Otherwise, it becomes personaly leads to a long discussion as this one, with no practical results, moreover causing hard feelings.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to *share knowledge*.  That includes sharing the knowledge of when  people are doing things wrong, and when there's a better way to accomplish the same thing, or when the solution you've chosen is far too heavyweight when there are much lighter ones available. Of course, the entire way this site works is based on the expectations that the people asking questions are actually here to gain knowledge, instead of just being insistent on doing things their way rather than learning anything. We know where you are.

Comment: @kobik: There's a place for stored procedures, absolutely. But using them to do an extremely simple SELECT to get a few rows of data isn't one of them, IMO. And if you read the start of this (in the poster's other question I linked above, the entire thing started with this poster trying to pass a parameter to a VIEW, and refusing to believe that it wasn't possible. Someone randomly mentioned that you could do it with a stored proc, and all of the sudden the aim switched to doing it with a stored proc. This poster is stuck on doing things his way, even when wrong. He's  not here to learn.

Comment: Ken, my friend, your not being fair. You are telling half the story. What you are mentioning about the view, was subject of another question.  In fact, the question was exactly about if it is possible or not to pass parameters, wich was answered as not. After that, I posted this current question about passing parameters to a SP, and in fact you stacked with the argument that I was doing wrong using a SP that way, wich you must agree, was not an answer. I think you may advice or warn the poster on what you consider an error, but is up to him to accept or not.

Comment: (continued) Or in your superior judgement, you think that we must say amen to anything you state without any disagreement? Seems to me somehow not democratic. I told you before and I repeat: be free to ignore my questions if they bother you that much (or I bother you). I do want to learn new things, but I prefer to select wich are of interest to me and preferable not from someone that try to impose to me its way of thinking. Kindly...

Comment: (continued) If you prefer, we can go on with this discussion on chat, so we can finally close this question.

Comment: I strongly protest aganinst the avaliation of this question!!! It is a good question and it is of general inerest. Many people who has the same issue will take advantage of it. Is not my fault if due to some users stubbornness  the discussion lost it focus! I ask the people who avaliated it to -3 to reconsider. Thanks.

Comment: I think somebody said somewhere " That includes sharing the knowledge of when people are doing things wrong" .... :)